# Why do I get errors for _setActiveMenu and _addBreadcrumb?

Tags: magento

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Desbest_Brands_Adminhtml_BrandsController::_addBreadcrumb() in
>   /home/desbest/public_html/clients/magentofull/app/code/local/Desbest/Brands/controllers/Adminhtml/BrandsController.php
>   on line 8
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Desbest_Brands_Adminhtml_BrandsController::_setActiveMenu() in
>   /home/desbest/public_html/clients/magentofull/app/code/local/Desbest/Brands/controllers/Adminhtml/BrandsController.php
>   on line 7

From what I see, the `Data.php` file inside `Helpers/` folder should be left as it is blank like what the tutorials say.

So what's with the errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you controller class is extended from `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`. You should extend it from `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` class instead, because only it has methods called `_addBreadcrumb()` and `_setActiveMenu()`.

Comment: ...and make sure to override `_isAllowed()` when you fix the class definition :-)